# What is a vertorama and is it really different from a panorama?

Tags: terminology, panorama

Is "vertorama" a real photography term, or is it simply something that [people use](http://www.flickr.com/groups/vertoramas/) to describe a vertical panorama? I never thought that panorama was limited to horizontal landscape oriented images, but is it? In other words, is every wide-angle horizontal image a panorama and every wide-angle vertical image a vertorama, and are they mutually exclusive or not? Further, is hororama or similar a term?

Comment: I think it will be fairly soon. Dictionaries are living documents, they record words as people use them. From @mattdm's answer, clearly people are using the term.

Comment: I think it remains to be seen; dictionaries are relatively conservative and not every neologism makes the grade, particularly if it doesn't appear often in print.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A panorama is, in its original usage, a wide angle horizontal image. In fact, it's a horizontal image painted in a complete circle around a room. That was in [the late 1700s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panoramic_painting), though, and by the time the idea got to photography, it had been watered down to some degree, generally describing any [image with a field of view greater than 100º](http://www.sav.org/e/panorama.html), and then eventually [any really wide image at all](http://www.blackandwhitelab.com/tips_pages/panoramic/panoramic.html). Through that same elasticity of language, it's clearly come to encompass vertical images as well, and continuing in that vein, there's not a clear-cut answer to your question.

On the one hand, "vertorama" is clearly a term people use, and it's pretty easy to understand immediately what's meant. It's hard to argue that it's "not a real term" when there's 12,000 pictures in a [Vertorama flickr pool](http://www.flickr.com/groups/vertoramas/); simply pragmatically, it's a *real enough* term for that.

But, is it a term with a *legacy* in photography (or the English language!)? For that, I turned to Google Books search, and couldn't find a single use before 2010. And in 2010, there's this:

> Vertical subjects are naturals for vertically oriented panorama (some people now refer to such images as "vertoramas" but we prefer simply "vertical panorama").
>        – [*Real World Digital Photography*, by Eismann, Duggan, and Grey](http://books.google.com/books?id=3kDYK6e5LnMC&pg=PT418&dq=vertorama+photography&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8TnuUJ2ROIr49QTm2YDABg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAg)

That's not particularly a ringing endorsement of the term, and what's more, it's the only book I find indexed that uses it. So, I'd say:

- It's a term people clearly are using and enjoy. It's clearly understandable, and maybe catchy and even clever if you're into that sort of wordplay.
- But it doesn't have a long history or broad acceptance.

If you are the sort of person who enjoys newly-invented portmanteau words, I'd say feel free to use it, but don't be surprised if others view that as a bit ecccentric.

Comment: As a postscript, I think _hororama_ is right out. It sounds silly and _isn't_ immediately understandable. It's unnecessary, as panorama captures the meaning already. And, as far as I can tell, you're the first person to _ever_ use it in a context other than a badly-spelled horror film marathon.

Comment: Great research. I saw the question and thought WTF? but did a Google search to find this used in a number of places but it is clearly not as popular than *panorama*, so this can be used to your advantage if you want to showcase that kind of work.

Comment: @Itai — great point. In art, being eccentric is not necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

A word created by combining two or more existing words is called a *portmanteau*, and they're quite common. A few examples that come to mind: Spanglish, Franglais, brunch, frenemy, motel, prosumer. It remains to be seen whether *vertorama* is useful or catchy enough to see widespread adoption, and it's surely not an acceptable Scrabble word yet, but I wouldn't hesitate to use it when it fits.

Comment: I understand that photography has it's own nomenclature, and a "word" can be anything commonly used. I was more interested if it historically is used or has very limited use on the internet, as well as it's relation to panorama.